# Crystal Reports- Export report causing "Missing Parameter Values"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, parameters, crystal-reports, export

I am trying to export a report but everytime it runs the code to export the crystal report in the crystalreportviewer I get an error message saying "Missing Parameter Values". I've looked through many sources but havent found a solution. I do know that all parameters are filled in because without the export code, the site runs perfectly fine.

Export code

```
Try
            Dim CrExportOptions As CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportOptions
            Dim CrDiskFileDestinationOptions As New  _
            CrystalDecisions.Shared.DiskFileDestinationOptions()
            Dim CrFormatTypeOptions As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.PdfRtfWordFormatOptions()
            CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = _
                                        "c:\crystalExport.pdf"
            CrExportOptions = oRpt.ExportOptions
            With CrExportOptions
                .ExportDestinationType = CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportDestinationType.DiskFile
                .ExportFormatType = CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat
                .DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions
                .FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions
            End With
            oRpt.Export()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex.ToString)
        End Try
```

Also:

```
  'Try
        '    oRpt.ExportToHttpResponse([Shared].ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, True, "ExportedReport")
        'Catch ex As Exception
        '    Response.Write(ex.ToString)
        'End Try
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve my own problem I found that the code actually exports the instance of the crystal report, whereas I was putting the parameters into the crystalreportviewer after providing the source. Instead I provided the parameters directly into the instance which gets pushed into the crystalreportviewer as a datasource.

:)

Answer (score 3):

This is caused under 2 reasons. 
Either, you're not passing(from the program) a required parameter which you have created in the report.
Or, you're passing a parameter to the report but you haven't created it in the report.

Comment: But without exporting the parameters are pushed through fine in the report. And I also have a parameter checker to ensure they are being filled.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was a subreport that was not correctly linked with the main report.

Check if all the parameters of the subreport is linked with the main report.

Cheers;

Answer (score 0):

1. Have to set required parameters
2. Set rpt.**SetDataSource**(dt) even DataTable records count is 0:

   ```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(data);
        if (dt?.Rows != null)
        {
          rpt.SetDataSource(dt);
          return true;
        }
   ```